# materials compatibility Blender 2.79 - 2.93.5

Tags: rendering, compatibility

I found a blender file online with some cool rendering I would like to use. It works fine with version 2.79, but if I open it with version 2.93.5 the rendering doesn't work anymore (pink objects are displayed after the rendering).
I am an absolute beginner with Blender, but I guess the difference between the two versions is in the nodes available for defining materials. In  particular, in the old version I have 'geometry', 'material', 'texture' and 'output' nodes, which seem to have been replaced or removed in the new version. They are displayed as 'undefined' nodes. I attached screenshots of the nodes in both versions below. Does anyone have any idea of which nodes I should use to replace the old nodes in version 2.93.5?
Any help is really appreciated!
[image: nodes in version 2.79]
[image: nodes in version 2.93.5]

Comment: Well, it's been so long that I have already forgot, someone may give you more information but Geometry node still exists, it is still called "Geometry", but it has different output values, for example **Front/back** is now called **backfacing** --- Those textures need to be changed to image textures and input textures that should be in them as in original... output is now Material output.... However I am not sure about that Material node

Comment: Hi :). The main problem is the material is made for Blender Render - a no longer supported render engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inputs:

- The `UV` socket has a `UV` node
- Front/Back is `Backfacing` from the new `Geometry` node (1 is Back, 0 is front)

For function nodes:

`blender render` materials have been deprecated. `Cycles` engine does not have an equivalent. The new `Eevee` engine is the closest. You can get.

- for the `Material` node. Create a new `Principled` node, and connect its BSDF through a `ShaderToRGB` node. Use this node's RGB color output instead the old Material node's.
- for the `Texture` node. If the texture is an image file, create a `Image Texture` node and hook it in instead. If the texture is a blender `Texture` object, you'll have to recreate it in the shader editor from the builtin procedural textures.
- there is a new `Output` node, plug the color into the `Surface` socket